# Uart communication with Hex-Code in C

Tags: c, hex, microcontroller, uart

I try to communicate with a olfactory sensor via uart and Hex-code, but it does not work, the sensor doesn't react on the manufaturers given commands.

Is there somethings wrong with my write function and the `uint_8` array?

```
//declaration of the hex array

uint8_t START_USM[7];

    START_USM[0]=0x01;
    START_USM[1]=0x00;
    START_USM[2]=0x03;
    START_USM[3]=0x31;
    START_USM[4]=0x00;
    START_USM[5]=0x00;
    START_USM[6]=0x00;

// function for transmitting data

int commmandWrite2(int fileDescriptor, uint8_t *START_USM){

    int i=0;
    for(; i< COM_LEN; i++){

        int n = write(fileDescriptor,&START_USM[i],1);
        tcdrain(fileDescriptor);

    }
}
```

Comment: you have to include your documentation.

Comment: What's the `write` function? Is it a function _you_ wrote, or is it a function provided by whatever? Please specify. In either case unveil the documentation of the `write`function.

Comment: Have you debugged it and verified that all data given to the write function is correct? Can you assume that the write function is correctly used and functional? Do you see the actual communication on the bus lines with an oscilloscope or over the serial port on your computer?

Comment: What is `COM_LEN` and why did you not use it to define the length of `START_USM[7]`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz The signature (and the fact that tcdrain, most likely from [termios(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios), is also used) strongly suggests that it is [write(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

Comment: I assume you tried the paperclip thing, and tied tx to rx, and received the bytes yourself, and/or you used another computer or another port to receive these bytes and confirmed the complete bytestream is going out in the right order?   And once you did that you called the sensor vendors tech support and they told you what?

Comment: Do you need a delay in between the writes?  What happens when you run it manually?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the sensor to a terminal?

Comment: UART... OK, how do you/we know that the problem is not hardware?   RS232-style serial links are notorious for not working for, like, a dozen different possible reasons:(

Comment: I proof the connection with RealTerm and there it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int commmandWrite2(int fileDescriptor, uint8_t *START_USM){

    int i=0;
    for(; i< COM_LEN; i++){

        int n = write(fileDescriptor,&START_USM[i],sizeof(uint8_t ));

    }
    tcdrain(fileDescriptor);
}
```

if the above works, than you can optimize it to

```
int commmandWrite2(int fileDescriptor, uint8_t *START_USM){
       int n = write(fileDescriptor,START_USM,sizeof(uint8_t )*COM_LEN);
        tcdrain(fileDescriptor);
}
```

Comment: The whole START_USM is the command for the sensor. I think i need the loop to send the whole command.